# How get path to folder "node_modules" in js file?

Tags: node.js

Node.js - 8.2.1

I my index.js I hard code path to **node_modules**:

'use strict';

```
var NPM_NODE_MODULES_BASE_DIR = 'd:\\Programs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\'

var express = require(NPM_NODE_MODULES_BASE_DIR + '\express'),
    bodyParser = require(NPM_NODE_MODULES_BASE_DIR +'body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

But it's not very good, because code is not portable. How I can get path to folder **node_modules** of Node.js ?

Comment: Why can't use just use `require('express')` like everyone else?  It seems the bigger question here is why is your system not configured appropriately so that you can just use `require()` with no path on the modules you have installed.  I'm not using a path on any of my `require()` statements.

Comment: How config system appropriately on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing npm modules globally you could install them in your src folder,  whenever you are in the src folder and do an npm install it should be installed in the local npm modules folder in the src file making it portable, you could use --save to add it to your dependencies so you can get it while initialising your node project

Comment: It's not good. If I has 10 projects in every projects I have same modules like "Express", "body-parser". It is diplicate

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excerpt from the nodejs current master branch source documentation [doc/api/modules.md]...

...high-level algorithm in pseudocode of what `require.resolve()` does:

require(X) from module at path Y

1. If X is a core module,
   a. return the core module

   b. STOP
2. If X begins with '/'
   a. set Y to be the filesystem root
3. If X begins with './' or '/' or '../'

   a. LOAD_AS_FILE(Y + X)

   b. LOAD_AS_DIRECTORY(Y + X)
4. LOAD_NODE_MODULES(X, dirname(Y))
5. THROW "not found"

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you can have more than one **node_modules** (see https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders).

*Most of the times*, the **node_modules** you want is the parent path of the directory your current module lives in:

```
const path = require('path').resolve(__dirname, '..');
```